# is there a way to switch from one app to another in C#?

Tags: c#, button, timer, switch-statement

Hi I have a new question for all fellow programmers to solve. Is there a way that I can press a button or have a timer on that will fire an event that will make my app switch from one app to another?  for example lets say I want to make a app that when i press a button it will switch from the current app to another app that is running like notepad or a game or something.

If there is a way to open a specific app by its name that would be great to, thanks.

PS: I already know how to code a timer so you don't have to post one if you don't want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the two WinAPI functions `FindWindow` and `SetFocus`, you can achieve your desired goal:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);
```

For example, to set a notepad window with the title "" to the foreground, you can use the following code:

```
SetFocus(FindWindow("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad"));
```

If you don't know the form's name, then you can enumerate the windows using other WinAPI functions.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `Interaction.AppActivate()` method from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`, found in namespace `Microsoft.VisualBasic` if you reference it.

Just simple call `Interaction.AppActivate("window title")` or `Interaction.AppActivate(iPID)`.

The appropriate documentation for this method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cf213249.aspx).

Comment: I think there's a easier method to do this look at the poster's question, I tried it but I can't seem to get it right though here's the link to it.  http://www.devmaster.net/forums/archive/index.php/t-4800.html

Comment: Thanks @mendez. I've updated my answer to show usage of the `Interaction.AppActivate()` method.

Comment: glad I could help, but since I'm still a noob at this I'm not sure how to implement this to work can you show me a more detailed example? just a simple button click to fire it would do thanks.

Comment: @mendez, `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0]);` should activate a notepad program if its running, otherwise it'll throw an exception.

Comment: for some reason I only get Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider what am i missing?

Comment: @mendez, You need to reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` as stated above: http://img847.imageshack.us/img847/8278/20110806173322.png

Comment: this is what I have so far, it gives me an error when I try it. Sorry for the inconvenience but I have never done this before.                 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }





        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0]);

Comment: @mendez let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2183/discussion-between-freedompeace-and-mendez)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pinvoke to call the SetFocus function which takes a WindowHandle and sets the keyboard focus to that screen.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646312(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.pinvoke.net for more information on how to use Pinvoke.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/147659 : A good article if you're unsure of what the window title is (if you do then you can just get all the window handles and then use GetWindowName() to get the window name and check if that's the one you want, GetWindowName also takes a window handle)